# Stop Vim from automatically tw=78 line-break wrapping text files

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, gvimrc

I recently updated Vim, and noticed that whenever I open a `.txt` file, the option `tw=78` is set. (Which makes Vim automatically break lines when they would have exceeded 78 characters.) I don't like that, and would like to get rid of it.

I added `set tw=0` as the last line in my `_vimrc` file, but that had no effect. I also looked at the different syntax and filetype files, but there seem to be none for TXT files.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution [on this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_use/__AjOEa2q6c/9mqWRmOVfCcJ). It turned out that since 2011, `vimrc_example.vim` was updated to include this `textwidth=78` rule as an autocommand, and my `_vimrc` sources `vimrc_example.vim` (probably because I based it on the original — which means this situation will apply for many users).

One solution is to find the line in your `.vimrc`, that says

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
```

And after that line, insert the following line to unset the particular autocommand that's making a nuisance:

```
au! vimrcEx FileType text
```

---

How I found the solution: I suspected that it was an autocommand, so I tried looking through all autocommands by using the `:autocmd` command. But there were just too many. To simplify things, I inserted that output into a spare buffer, as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198073/32647). Searching for `tw=78` showed the culprit autocommand with the keyword `vimrcEx`, and then asking Google for the keyword (or I could have grepped Vim's directory) lead us to the solution.

Comment: I've just upvoted your answer but thought I should mention that a quick and easy way to find out which file was used to set the `textwidth` (or any) option is to run `:verbose set tw?`.